# Understanding Wildcards in ENUM Responses

Tags: dns, bind, wildcards

I have just started working on ENUM and we get some RR and Answers which are like these

```
IN  NAPTR 100 10 "u" "E2U+sip" "!^44(.*)$!sip:9739668530@isp.example.com;user=phone!" .
```

I want to understand how do these wildcards/Regular Expressions work and How and why are they used in ENUM?

```
like.."!^44(.*)$!
```

Could I get any links or RFCs which could explain what these wildcards mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NAPTR record type is defined in [RFC 3403](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3403). It refers to [RFC 3402](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3402) for the general algorithm and the regular expression syntax.

The latter describes substitutions as "a combination of a POSIX Extended Regular Expression and a replacement string similar to Unix sed-style substitution expression." (Which both are *very* common syntaxes and you can find dozens of regex tutorials in a minute.)

The entire parameter has this syntax:

```
<separator>  <regex>  <separator>  <substitution>  <separator>
```

e.g.

```
!<regex>!<substitution>!
```

So `^44(.*)$` is the regular expression in POSIX syntax, and `sip:9739668530...` would be the substitution. This means that the whole phone number – if it starts with `44` – is replaced by the sip URL.

Again, I won't copy the *plenty* of existing regex documentation here. (You don't need to search for POSIX specifically – a very similar syntax is used by PCRE regexes, JavaScript regexes, Python regexes, etc. only differing in advanced features.)